# Script Runner: handle custom field with space sin expressions

Tags: jira, jql

I have a custom User Picker (single user) field. This field has a space in the name (e.g. "User Picker"). I cannot remove the space from this name as it is used in searches by many other people.

I want to search for all the issues where the `assignee != User Picker`. I installed Script Runner and added this in the advanced search:

```
issuefunction in expression("", "assignee != User Picker")
```

I got the error:

```
expecting EOF, found 'Picker' @ line 1, column 25.
```

I then searched the net and found that I should be able to use a custom field ID. For example, for `cf[12345]` I should be able to use:

```
issuefunction in expression("", "assignee != customfield_12345")
```

This results in the error:

```
Field customfield_12345 not found or not a Number or Date custom field.
```

Is there a way of using User Picker custom fields with spaces in expressions?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the *expression* issueFunction is available [here](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/jql-functions.html#_expression).

It mentions:

> What you can compare are the system estimate and date fields, and any numeric, date, or datetime custom field.

You're trying to compare User fields, but *expression* cannot be used for that.

To get the functionality that you're looking for, you'll have to implement your own [custom JQL function](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/custom-jql-functions.html).